# присвоить значения одного массива к элементам другого

Tags: php

Подскажите плз как присвоить значения одного массива к другому(сделать словарь). Например есть 2 массива со значениями:

```
$id=array(55,60)
$email=array("first@.com","second@.com")
```

А в итоге чтобы получился один массив с двумя значениями (если не считать индексов элемента):

```
$myData=array(55:"first@.com",60:"second@.com")
```

Comment: `array_combine` (если 55 и 60 должны быть ключами)

Comment: спасибо, круто, и без каких либо циклов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r(array_combine($id, $email));
```